# Function for pickle

Tags: python, function, pickle

I am trying to build a function to store data in a pickle file. 
I know that using pickle this way works:

```
with open('x.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(x, f)
```

But I actually want to make a function out of it so I don't have to write it again and again. Here is what I have tried:

```
def pickle_dump(x):
    with open('%s.pickle'%x, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(x, f)
    return
```

When we use 'with', and the file does not exist, it creates a file. I supposed that it would also work when inside a function, but instead it returned me a File Not Found Error.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hm, that's very strange... are you *sure* you are using `'wb'` argument in `pickle_dump`? Because testing your code it works fine for me..,

Comment: I think you want to pass a `filename` explicitly...

Comment: The string representation of your object `x` can contain arbitrary characters that are invalid in a filename.  If you were expecting this to produce a file literally named `x.pickle`, just because the parameter was named `x`, that's not how Python works - objects generally have no idea what their name is.

Comment: Should I not use the return? I thought every function had to have one. I just want to create a pickle file that I can retrieve later on. @BradSolomon

Comment: @jasonharper That's exactly what I wanted to do... How does Python work, then?

Comment: A `return` with no successive expression is as good as none. It is redundant. Python functions will `return [None]` by default. So you can safely drop it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What do you mean by 'are you sure you are using 'wb' argument in pickle_dump?' I thought the middle part was ok. I am just havng problems creating the function itself.

Comment: Think about it this way - the *actual name of the variable you see* is not something Python should ever have to know about. Indeed, in general, the objects have no idea that they are assigned to some variable named `x` or `foo` or `banana`. Sure, if you do metaprogramming black-magic, *maybe* you want to directly mess with `globals()` or `locals()` where this could be extracted, but valid cases for that are few-and-far in-between.

Comment: That was just a guess - I think @jasonharper has the right idea.

Comment: There is no issue in wanting to have the object's string representation to be the pickled filename. In fact in some cases you might be wanting that. But as @jasonharper pointed out there might be special characters in your String representation of the object, in linux it could be `/`, in windows it could be any one of `|*?\` etc... So would suggest printing x before the open statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're confusing the string path name with your actual object.  They are two different things.

```
def pickle_dump(path, x):
   """Pickle object `x` to `path`."""
    with open('%s.pickle' % path, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(x, f)
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = DataFrame() # the actual object you want to pickle
pickle_dump(path='files/filename', x=df)
```

To do the same thing in reverse:

```
def pickle_load(path): 
    with open('%s.pickle' %path, 'rb') as f: 
        return pickle.load(f)
```

Now to run this you would assign a variable to the returned value from the function:

```
result = pickle_load('mypath/filename')
```

In your comment, you named a variable `x` in the function body.  But realize that is a *local* variable.  You can't access it from outside of the function.  That's a case where you want the return statement.

Comment: I tried following you on this to do the pickle_load function like this:

def pickle_load(path):
    with open('%s.pickle' %path, 'rb') as f:     
        x = pickle.load(f)

Why is this not correct?

Answer (score 1):

Pass both the object and filename.

```
import cPickle as pickle  # Python 2

def pickle_dump(obj, filename):
    if filename.split('.')[-1] != 'p':
        filename += '.p'  # Add pickle file extension `.p` if needed.
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(obj, f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```